# Not having a getter method in POJO does not set the values via setter method

Tags: java, json, setter, getter-setter, pojo

I am using `org.json` library for JSON parsing. I have experienced that when I have two methods say `getName()` and `setName()` and if I comment the getter method in my `POJO` class, the setter method also does not work .

But if i don't, it works. Why this happens? Can't we just set the value in `POJO` and convert to JSON string?

Comment: It might be easier to help if you were to post a [MCVE](http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which reproduces this issue.

Answer (score 1):

> Can't we just set the value in the POJO and convert to a JSON string?

If you comment out the getter method, the JSON library will no longer serialize the property, because it has no way to get the property.